# How to reuse common subelements of a custom UITableViewCell with iOS Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have several custom `UITableViewCell`, which share a lot of common subelements.

I tried creating a `UIView` and using it as a subview for all the table cells, but obviously this wouldn't work, since entities in IB are object instances, not classes or templates.

How can I capture these common subelements in a custom control and drag it into all table cells? Ideally it would be a solution where one doesn't have to muck around with programmatic Nib loading and whatnot.

Comment: Probably there is no solution for this in IB. IB is for layout only ;) You will have to do this programmatically I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "easiest" answer would be to create your CustomSubview class with the common, shared elements programmatically, and then in IB add a UIView subview and give it the class of CustomSubview. You'll have to write the subview in code, but you will still be able to reuse it in your various xibs.